# Laravel 8 hasmanythrough (?) with multiple pivot tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

category_product table (manyToMany):

```
id
category_id
product_id
```

price_rules table:

```
id
title
discount_template_id
start
end
```

category_price_rule table (manyToMany):

```
id
category_id
price_rule_id
```

How can I get a discount template for a product (the discount template should be taken from the latest by id price rule)? Currently I have this method:

```
private function price_rule_dt() {
    $dt = NULL;
    foreach($this->categories as $category) {
        if($category->price_rules->count() > 0) {
            $dt = $category->price_rules->first->discount_template;
        } 
    }
    return $dt;
}
```

It works but it doesn't get the latest discount template. Also, debugbar shows duplicate generated models and it requires messy eager loading each time I try to load the products:

```
Product::with('categories.price_rules.discount_template')->get();
```

I believe it should be something like:

```
Product::with('price_rule_dt')->get();
```

Is there a better way around this than I have now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a solution like this:

```
public function category_price_rules()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        CategoryPriceRule::class,
        CategoryProduct::class,
        'product_id', 
        'category_id', 
        'id', 
        'category_id' 
    )->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
...
Product::with('category_price_rules.price_rule.discount_template')->get();
```

It doesn't generate unnecessary category models, looks cleaner and gets the latest (by price rule) discount template.